# Cannot count the successful requests of web scraped pages using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to log for a start how many successful requests with status 200 I have after I complete the web scraping of a page I use the following part

```
import requests
import csv
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import sleep
import datetime

mycount = 0 

class Parser(object):

    ses = requests.Session()

    # parse a single item to get information
    def parse(self, urls):
        url = urls[1]

        try:
            r = self.ses.get(url)
            time.sleep(3)
            if r.status_code == 200:

                mycount=mycount+1
```

and later one when I have mycount to pass it to a list and a csv

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(4) as p:

        print('Just before parsing..Page')
        records = p.map(parser.parse, web_links)
        with open(my_log_path,'a',encoding='utf-8',newline='') as logf:
            writer = csv.writer(logf,delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow(logs)
```

But I get that my **local variable is referenced before assignment**
Why mycount is treated as local variable if it is on the top and outside a function? How can I fix this?
thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Your class does not have access to mycount because it's a global variable. You should use `global` inside your class before modifying it:

```
def parse(self, urls):
        global mycount
        url = urls[1]
```

Comment: Maybe you want to post full code or context and full stack error because I have tried this on my local env and it works.